# Equation involving absolute values of several quantities

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the sum of the values of x that satisfy $| x + 1 | + 3|x-2| + 5|x-4| = 20$.

My approach-
I tried to put the + and - value in each of the modulo but it got too complicated. The answer should be a single digit number.

Comment: draw a sign curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name of the game is to figure out the regions that determine the signs for the quantities $x-4, x-2$ and $x+1$.

Case 1. $x\geqslant 4$ implies all the quantities are nonnegative.

Case 2. $2\leqslant x < 4$ implies $x+1 > x-2\geqslant 0$ and $x-4<0$.

Case 3. $-1\leqslant x < 2$ implies $x+1\geqslant 0$ and $x-4< x-2<0$.

Case 4. $x< -1$ implies all quantities are negative.

Take case 2, for instance. Assuming $2\leqslant x<4$ we have
$$x+1 + 3x-6 + 20 -5x=20 \Rightarrow x=-5,$$
which is not allowed. So case 2 yields no solutions. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but I have a doubt here,
While calculating for x we've taken only the positive values in all the modulo's what about the other signs?